# Momentary freeze in Mac OS X on attaching a USB device

Tags: macos, macbook-pro, usb, performance, sd-card

This seems to have started only recently, but every time I attach a USB device or removable media (SD Card) to my MacBook Pro running OS X 10.8.3 the mouse cursor freezes for a few seconds. The screen is still updating. It seems to happen right when the OS sees the external drive (via phone, camera, SD card, etc.)

I don't see a spike in CPU or anything else suspect, just that the trackpad stops responding momentarily. What would cause this and is there a way to fix it?

Comment: I am getting the same thing. It only seems to have happened recently - last few weeks. This is 10.8.2 which has been running for a few months.

Comment: @fredders: Mine stopped after a reboot. Hearing I am not the only one with the symptom means it may be reproducible. I'll keep you posted.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Do you happen to have the Android File Transfer application installed? Various [users on macrumors](http://forums.macrumors.com/showthread.php?t=1454562) have noted the same issue, and have narrowed it down to having AFT installed.

I'm getting the same problem, and I too have AFT installed, but I won't be removing it any time soon as it's the only way to get anything to/from my Android devices.

Comment: I do have AFT installed, and it seems like it probably started shortly after installing it. Luckily it seems that after rebooting it stopped. I'll try launching AFT or connecting an Android device and see if that causes it to happen again.

Comment: Yes, sir, that was the cause. Luckily it only seems to be for Android devices now.

Comment: Question is, when is Google going to fix it?

Comment: May God bless you. Here's where I found the offending app, in addition to inside the Applications folder: ``/Users/YourUsername/Library``

Comment: FWIW: AirDroid (www.airdroid.com) is a good free alternative to AFT, has a bunch of features including wireless transfer of files between Mac and Android devices.